# Xcode app, navigation bar not showing on iPhone 6

Tags: swift, xcode, video, navigationbar

I have an app that has been out for some time. I recently updated it to Swift. I have one user who is seeing different results than I am on either the simulator or on two different devices. The view presented is for video playing and on my devices and the simulator the navigation bar is present and the control bar for the video, unless the screen is tapped to dismiss it. On my user's iPhone 6 there is no navigation and no control bar.

[image: iPhone 6 screen view]

[image: iPhone 6 simulator view]

I have not called for the navigation bar to be hidden on that view.

Haas anyone any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: are you setting `showsPlaybackControls` to false somewhere in your code

Comment: My movie player control are set to;    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.embedded

Comment: My user re-downloaded the app and now the Controls show but the navigation bar is hidden on all views.

Comment: I really don't know what you did in there or how you are showing your views

Comment: I solved the issue by adding in viewWillAppear: self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false  That fixed the issue, but I still don't understand why it worked on my devices and not my user's device.